# How do I limit characters using JQuery in Django?

Tags: python, django

I want to limit users to only placing five characters for the zip code. Here's what I have so far (that doesn't seem to work). What I'm going for is if someone accidentally submits more than five characters, then the script will delete off all but the five most recent characters. Is this the best route?

**sign-up.html**

```
<script>
          var max_chars = 5;

          $('#zip_length').keydown( function(e){
              if ($(this).val().length >= max_chars) {
                  $(this).val($(this).val().substr(0, max_chars));
              }
          });

          $('#zip_length').keyup( function(e){
              if ($(this).val().length >= max_chars) {
                  $(this).val($(this).val().substr(0, max_chars));
              }
          });
      </script>
...
<form action="" method="POST" class="mt-4" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            {% crispy form %}
                        </form>
...
```

**forms.py**

```
...
 zip = forms.CharField(label='Zip', required=True,
                          widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter your zip', 'id': 'zip_length'}))
...

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProfileUpdateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            ...
            Row(
                Column('city', css_class='form-group col-4'),
                Column('state', css_class='form-group col-4'),
                Column('zip', css_class='form-group col-4')
            ),
            ...
        )
```

Comment: I wouldn't truncate the user's input - maybe they made a typo? Instead if they enter more than 5 characters, have your validator return an error and make it clear to the user they need to resubmit the form with the proper input. Also, a lot of countries have postal codes longer than 5 characters -- keep that in mind if you even have the possibility of having a non-US user (and even in the US, some people prefer Zip+4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are looking for a [form length validator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/validators/#maxlengthvalidator).

Actually you could write it like that:

```py
zip = forms.CharField(label='Zip', max_length=5, min_length=5 required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter your zip', 'id': 'zip_length'}))
```

I'm not sure what's your use case, however the most user-friendly way of dealing with this error is to display an error message to the user so she can correct the input. If you truncate the last part silently maybe it makes the input technically correct but wrong from the user's point of view.

Also Jim is right, maybe zipcode will not be 5 chars long for all your users.

Comment: This worked well. Thank you. If the website I'm creating is popular with people outside of the US, I'll hand over the keys to someone more knowledgeable than me and stick to Java. ha